# Create View create a new error that wasn't there before

Tags: sql, database

My request was working very well til I created a View and I got the error :

> Error in the request (1060): Duplicate column name 'nom'

What does it mean ??

````
CREATE VIEW requete3 AS
SELECT joueurs.nom,joueurs.prenom,joueurs.numero,equipes.nom, MAX(joueurs.moyenne) as "moyenne"
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes ON joueurs.equipeId = equipes.equipeId
GROUP BY joueurs.equipeId ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can give an alias to duplicate column name as following

```
CREATE VIEW requete3 AS
SELECT 
  joueurs.nom as nom_joueurs,
  joueurs.prenom,
  joueurs.numero,
  equipes.nom as non_equipes, 
  MAX(joueurs.moyenne) as "moyenne"
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes 
ON joueurs.equipeId = equipes.equipeId
GROUP BY joueurs.equipeId
```

Answer (score 0):

it have two columns with the same name `nom` so there will be conflict. Try to give ailas using `as`

```
CREATE VIEW requete3 AS
SELECT joueurs.nom as nom1,joueurs.prenom,joueurs.numero,equipes.nom as nom2, MAX(joueurs.moyenne) as "moyenne"
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes ON joueurs.equipeId = equipes.equipeId
GROUP BY joueurs.equipeId
```